# MySQL multiple IN conditions to subquery with same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple IN conditions with subqueries.

```
SELECT
    S.name,
    S.email
FROM something S
WHERE 
    1 NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE somethingId = S.id)
    AND 2 NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE somethingId = S.id)
    AND 3 NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE somethingId = S.id)
```

Maybe there are better solutions? Something like:

```
    (1, 2, 3) NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE somethingId = S.id)
```

Comment: Do a NOT EXISTS instead. (Which is also null-safe.)

Comment: You should prefere `JOIN` or `EXISTS()` as they are faster and more flexible in many situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-write to use `NOT EXISTS` instead. I.e return from S when there is no row in tags with somethingId equals to s.id and id is 1, 2 or 3.

```
SELECT
    S.name,
    S.email
FROM something S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tags WHERE id in (1, 2, 3) and somethingId = S.id)
```

Also `NOT EXISTS` is "null-safe". (`NOT IN (select returning a null)` will return no rows at all.)

Comment: I'm idiot... I could thought about that my self... :( Thank you. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.