# WHERE (set) IN (set)

Tags: mysql, sql

EDIT: I seemed to have asked this question incorrectly.

I'm trying to find a way to query if a set is available in another set. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM something
WHERE (1, 3) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

In this case, 1 & 3 are in the set (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). Another example:

```
SELECT * FROM something
WHERE (1, 3) IN (1, 5, 7, 9);
```

In this case, 1 & 3 ARE NOT in the set (1, 5, 7, 9) so nothing should be pulled from the table.

Comment: This seems to be asking the same and has been solved earlier this day - [MySQL multiple IN conditions to subquery with same table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480785/mysql-multiple-in-conditions-to-subquery-with-same-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW REQUEST (according to  sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f36d92/2):**

```
# The goal is to write a query that will select all exercises
# that the user has the correct equipment for, where the pre-defined
# set is the id's of the equipment the user has.

# For example, let's assume the user has equipment (1, 4)
# The exercise "Curls" should be pulled from the table, as the user has all
# of the required equipment based on the exercise_requirements table. 
# while "Wrecking Ball" is not returned as the user only has a portion of the
# required equipment.

# If the user's equipment was (1, 3, 4) then both "Curls" and "Wrecking ball"
# would be returned from the exercises table, as the user has the required equipment
# for both exercises.

#----

#Below is my take on your query.
```

```
SELECT ex.* FROM exercises ex
WHERE ex.id IN (
  SELECT exercise_id FROM exercise_requirements
  WHERE ex.id IN (1, 4)
  GROUP BY exercise_id
  HAVING COUNT(distinct exercise_id) = 3
);
```

**SOLUTION:**

You are confusing some IDs here. This would be closer:

```
SELECT ex.* FROM exercises ex
WHERE ex.id IN (
  SELECT exercise_id FROM exercise_requirements
  WHERE equipment_id IN (1, 4)
  GROUP BY exercise_id
  HAVING COUNT(distinct equipment_id) = 2
);
```

But still this query is vice versa. We don't want to know whether all the user's equipment are found in a set of equipment needed for an exercise, but whether the whole set of equipment needed for an exercise is found in the user's equipment.

Probably the easiest way to write this is: aggregate `exercise_requirements` per `exercise_id` and check that no `equipment_id` is needed that the user doesn't have.

```
select * 
from exercises
where id in
(
  select exercise_id
  from exercise_requirements
  group by exercise_id
  having sum(equipment_id not in (1, 4)) = 0
);
```

Your updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f36d92/5

Comment: Absolutely genius. Gotta think outside of the box sometimes. I was so determined on having "X numbers IN Y numbers" that collecting a sum of the numbers NOT IN Y didn't even cross my mind.

Answer (score 4):

NOTE:  This answers the original question, which seems to have nothing to do with the question after OP modifications.

You can get the users who completed all three levels by using:

```
SELECT cl.user_id
FROM completed_levels cl
WHERE cl.id IN (3, 5, 7)
GROUP BY cl.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cl.id) = 3;
```

(Note:  `DISTINCT` is not necessary if the ids for a given user are unique.)

THEN, you can get what you want using a `JOIN` or similar construct:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u JOIN
     (SELECT cl.user_id
      FROM completed_levels cl
      WHERE cl.id IN (3, 5, 7)
      GROUP BY cl.user_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cl.id) = 3
     ) cu
     ON cl.user_id = u.id;
```

Comment: Really, @Gordan has intellectual ability to answer. Salute & +1

Comment: Hey @Gordon,  Thanks for the answer, I seemed to have published my edit immediately after you hit send, would you mind reviewing the questions edit? I asked the wrong question without realizing it, or rather, asked the question incorrectly.

Thanks.

Comment: @Hobbyist . . . You should have asked another question.  Your original question was quite clear and has little to do with the revision.

Comment: I agree. And the sqlfiddle given in a comment to my original answer is yet another task, which would best have been put in a new request. (I've answered this here, though, in order to help along).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `IN` clause with a correlated subquery (i.e. the subquery references `u.id`). This is not how we use it. The `IN` clause is great for non-correlated subqueries; if you need a correlated subquery, use `EXISTS` instead. For your problem a non-correlated subquery suffices, so use `IN` accordingly:

```
select *
from users
where u.id in (select user_id from completed_levels where id in (1, 5, 7);
```

If a user must have *all* levels:

```
select *
from users
where u.id in (select user_id from completed_levels where id = 1
  and u.id in (select user_id from completed_levels where id = 5
  and u.id in (select user_id from completed_levels where id = 7;
```

Such problems are usually better solved with an aggregation so as not to have to query the same table again and again:

```
select *
from users
where u.id in 
(
  select user_id 
  from completed_levels where id in (1, 5, 7)
  group by user_id
  having count(distinct id) = 3
);
```

Comment: I seemed to have asked this question incorrectly. My question is actually how to make sure that all of a set is contained in a different set. For example.. WHERE (1, 5) IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) would be true, and WHERE (1, 5) IN (1, 2, 4, 7, 8) would be false. The query needs to be constructed dynamically, so I'm trying to avoid a bunch of AND calls.

Comment: Okay, I understand that now. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Please review the question edit which is reflected in my comment. +1 for the answer to the incorrectly asked question.

Comment: I think that my last query as well as Gordon's answer still match your edited question. If you want to know whether both (1, 3) are in (1, 5, 7, 9) and you don't want to have two expressions (`1 in (1,5,7,9) AND 3 in (1,5,7,9`) then select 1 and 3 from (1, 5, 7, 9) and count matches (here you have only one match for two values, so the values are not all in the set).

Comment: I've created a SQLFiddle with a use case and perhaps you will see my confusion. Thanks for all of the help, would be happy to donate to you if you have a PayPal if we can get this figured out. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f36d92/2

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN completed_levels cl
ON cl.user_id = u.id
WHERE cl.id IN (1, 5, 7);
```

Or using `EXISTS` as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480785/mysql-multiple-in-conditions-to-subquery-with-same-table) from @DanFromGermany

Comment: This does not work, this returns all users that have completed either level 1, 5, or 7. The query needs to select users that have completed levels 1, 5 AND 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Case` to make a `Sum` which will increase with 1 for each level within 1, 5 & 7.

```
SELECT A.* FROM users AS
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT U.id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN 
      (
         A.completed_levels = 1 
         OR A.completed_levels = 5 
         OR A.completed_levels = 7
      ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   ) AS RN
FROM completed_levels A
INNER JOIN users U ON A.user_id = U.id
GROUP BY U.id
) B ON A.id = B.id 
WHERE B.RN = 3 -- Those users have completed level 1, 5 & 7 will have RN = 3 only
```

Comment: I seemed to have asked this question incorrectly. My question is actually how to make sure that all of a set is contained in a different set.  For example.. `WHERE (1, 5) IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` would be true, and `WHERE (1, 5) IN (1, 2, 4, 7, 8)` would be false. The query needs to be constructed dynamically, so I'm trying to avoid a bunch of `AND` calls.